# Internet Explorer 11 border on ::after pseudo element bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

we have a strange bug in IE 11.
We made a pure CSS button with an after and before pseudo element. Everything looks fine, except in Internet Explorer.

Here is our CSS:

```
.arrow{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 37px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  border-left: 0px dotted #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  top: 4px;
  right: -13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px; 
    width: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url('../arrow_left.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I can't upload a picture of our button. We're always getting a strange, thin left border on the ::after pseudo element although we're setting it to border-left: none.

Does anyone have an idea why we're getting this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's an anchor Tag...

<a class="arrow" href="#">Content...</a>

Comment: OK... Well, I can't really see the difference between EI11 and other browsers, sorry. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Lrd7bk1z/1/). Can you put up a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have no rights to upload a screenshot :(

Comment: Just upload the screenshot somewhere that we can take a look at.